# What is the meaning of $\delta(x, y)$ in the definition of eventual recognizability?

Tags: logic, notation, set-theory

The book “Ordinal Computability” [Merlin Carl] contains the following text (Definition 4.5.1):

> $x$ is called “eventually recognizable” or “limit recognizable” if and only if there is a
> program $P$ such that, for all $y \subseteq \omega$, the output of $P^y$ eventually stabilizes at $\delta(x, y)$ (but the computation may not halt).

What is the meaning of “$\delta(x, y)$” here? What mathematical entity does this notation imply?

**EDIT**

If “$\delta(x, y)$” is the same as “$\delta_{x, y}$” (described before Definition 4.0.1 in the book), then it is the Kronecker symbol, i.e., $\delta(x, y) = 1$ if and only if $x = y$, and otherwise $\delta(x, y) = 1$. My understanding is as follows:

> A machine is given an arbitrary input $y$. If $x = y$, then the output $z$ of the machine eventually stabilizes at $1$. Otherwise, $z$ eventually stabilizes at $0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you can check in the Index...

Comment: Good point.....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. Here, $\delta(x,y)$ is just another way to write the Kronecker symbol and the definition then means exactly what you say in your edit.